# Cannot convert value of type 'NavigationLink<some View, EditView>' to closure result type '_'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NavigationLink' to
>   closure result type '_'

Do you know what's wrong here?

My ContentView file:

```
@ObservedObject var voucherData = VoucherData()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(voucherData.voucherList) { voucher in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditView(value:voucher.value, currency: voucher.currency, shopName: voucher.shopName)) {
                            VStack() {
```

And in an other file:

```
struct Voucher : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var value : String = ""
    var currency : String = ""
    var shopName : String = ""
}

final class VoucherData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var voucherList: [Voucher] = [
        .init(value: "100", currency: "USD", shopName: "FlyBurger")]
}
```

Comment: Is there some code missing from the `ContentView` code you've posted? It looks like more lines or more closing brackets are missing

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing in there that has to do with this error. Just the layout with some HStacks and Vstacks and also links to the data like "voucher.currency". But I also get the error when I comment it out.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's unfortunately very hard to say what could be going wrong. I copied the code you gave and filled it in as simply as possible in a new project and had no error.

Comment: there are 2 other files in the project with the same variables, connected by     `@Binding var value : String
@Binding var currency : String
@Binding var shopName : String`
but in those files there are no errors.

Comment: Is it possible to send you my project?

Comment: I see the same error in my project and have no explanation so far. In contrast to your approach I am using List(voucherData.voucherList) {voucher in ... instead of ForEach but the compiler error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your EditView is just missing the parameter voucher:

```
struct EditView: View {

    let voucher: Voucher

    ...
}
```

Now you can pass the voucher like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EditView(voucher: voucher)) {
```